# how to remove white space from url in php

Tags: php

i am trying to remove white space from my url because i am using the url variable to query something in the database. but i keep getting %20 in my url which causes the database to return no values of such entry.

how can i remove it so that it doesnt cause this issue?

now this is what i tried but so far it is not working:

```
$userName = $row['username'];
            $escapeUpper = str_replace('%20','',"$userName");
```

how can i remove white spaces "%20" from my url?

Comment: Hi, ‘url_decode’ should do the trick: [php url_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) this automatically converts the url variable to normal text. Oh and, to get the variable from the url you should do: ‘$username = $_GET[“username”];’ or something similar

Comment: You should rather try and fix the _actual_ problem - altough with what info you have given so far, it is rather unclear, what that is. If you passed this value via URL, then PHP should have already reverted any URL encoding, before it makes this value available via $_GET. But your “code sample” gets the value from `$row['username']`, so it is very unclear what connection that is supposed to have to values passed via URL in the first place.

Comment: @Chiel i just tried the urldecode and it didnt work unfortunately

Comment: @ChrisJamal which variable did you decode? In any case, don’t decode the variable in the database, rather decode the actual url variable

Comment: @Chiel `$userName = $row['username'];
   $escapeUpper = urldecode($userName);`

Comment: @ChrisJamal i see. I guess $row[‘username’] is the one you get from the mysql query. Which means that it shouldn’t contain %20 right? If you want to get the variable from the URL then you should do this: ‘url_decode($_GET[“username”]);’ if your url is something like: https://example.com/folder/index.php?username=Chris%20Jamal

Comment: I dont know what kind of PHP you are using but if you have a string like `$url = "Hello%20My%20Name%20is%20PHP";`  you can easily decode this using `urldecode($url)`. and it will remove any characters like %## , and spaces will decoded to the `+` sign.

Comment: @blacksheep so i cant do this with database? because i need to decode if any user has spaces in his username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around $userName

$escapeUpper = str_replace('%20','',$userName);

Comment: What's the value you are getting on $row['username'] ?

Comment: any users username in my database, but if a user has a space in his user name, lets say in my instance now i have "whatever whateve" the url makes it look like "whatever%20whateve" which makes it not go to the users profile

Comment: sorry you are trying to get the %20 as one space then this should work $escapeUpper = str_replace('%20',' ',$userName); a even better way is urldecode but seems it doesnt work for you as well. So suggest to post more details on how you get the values in $row['username']

Comment: i get the values of $row['username'] from my users database.

Comment: I am bit unclear  .. I understood that you got the value into $row['username'] from a DB, in that case somehow the '%20' ended up getting stored in the DB - which shouldn't happen isn't it? i mean if you have control over the code that stored this in the DB in the first place then please fix that?